# ipconfig /flushdns doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, dns

I have an outdated DNS entry on my Windows 7 PC, and can't seem to get rid of it.

- I've run `ipconfig  /flushdns` in an admin command line
- The hosts file is empty except for localhost
- I've restarted the PC

None of that has helped. I see the correct IP address using nslookup.

Comment: Can you add more detail, is this an external server or something on the local network? Is it a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - the main and backup DNS servers had conflicting data, and for some reason `nslookup` used the main and everything else used the backup, reinserting the wrong entry into the cache every time.

Comment: Hey I'm having this problem too. `nslookup` is showing the correct answer but everything else is still using the wrong answer. How did you flush the backup?

Comment: @Pacerier: the backup DNS server had wong data, it just needed to be configured correctly.